# cv2 findArucoMarkers sees marker from far away but doesn't draw center point until closer

Tags: python, opencv, aruco, webots

The Aruco marker is detected on the img but isn't fully detected because the cv2 drawing functions don't appear on the img until I'm closer to the marker.

I also have white boarders around the marker which helps a lot but this is different.

My code works but I don't understand why cv2 doesn't draw the center point of the marker from far away when there's already a green square detecting the marker from the `findArucoMarkers()` function.

Here's what I see using the simulation.
[Doesn't see center point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH1EV.png)

[See's center point when a "little" closer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZdsC.png)

````
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco

def findArucoMarkers(img, markerSize=4, totalMarkers=50, draw=True):
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    key = getattr(aruco, f"DICT_{markerSize}X{markerSize}_{totalMarkers}")
    arucoDict = aruco.Dictionary_get(key)
    arucoParam = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    aruco.detectMarkers(imgGray, arucoDict, parameters=arucoParam)
    bboxs, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(imgGray, arucoDict, parameters=arucoParam)

    # print(ids)
    if draw:
        aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(img, bboxs)

    return [bboxs, ids]

def marker_finder():

    # Gets img from simulator for vc to read
    sendDeviceImage(robot, display)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("display.jpg")

    # Load Image
    ret, img = cap.read()
    findArucoMarkers(img, 4, 100, True)
    arucoFound = findArucoMarkers(img)

    # Loop through all the markers and augments
    if len(arucoFound[0]) != 0:
        for bbox, ids in zip(arucoFound[0], arucoFound[1]):
            print(f"ID: {ids}")

            # Get sides of marker
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(bbox)
            # Get center point of b-rect
            c_x = x + w // 2
            c_y = y + h // 2
            center = [c_x, c_y]
            print(center)
            radius = 2
            cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (255, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(33)

    # Removes img from simulator
    cleanup()```
````

Comment: In the marker finder function, why have you called the findArucoMarkers function twice that too with different params? Comment out the upper call and check it again.

Comment: @RahulKedia Your right, it was the extra `findArucoMarkers` function. Thank you!!